# How can I parse using URLSession and import them in an array in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

So I have this object:

```
class Messages: NSObject {
   var id: String?
   var date: String?
   var text: String?
}
```

And I am parsing data using URLSession and then I want to create an array to add the messages in it. The problem is when I print `messages.id` or `messages.text` I can see the data but when I append them in an array: `messagesSet = [Messages]()` and print the text of the array I get something like [].

Here is the code to parse the data:

```
//Initiate Getting Messages
func getMessages(url: URL, completion: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        (data, response, error) in
        self.didFetchMessages(data: data, response: response!, error: error, completion: completion)
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}

//Callback for URLSession for getMessages
private func didFetchMessages(data: Data?, response: URLResponse, error: Error?, completion: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
        guard let messageList = jsonData["messages"] as? [Any] else {
            completion(nil, false)
            return
        }
        for messageInfo in messageList {
            let message = Messages()

            guard let info = messageInfo as? [String:Any] else {
                completion(nil, false)
                return
            }
            if let id = info["id"] as? String {
                message.id = id
            }
            if let date = info["date"] as? String {
                message.date = date
            }
            if let text = info["text"] as? String {
                message.text = text
            }
            messagesSet.append(message)
            print(messagesSet)
        }
        completion(messagesSet, true)
    } catch let error {
        print("Decoding error \(error)")
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.. I hope this info are enough to find the solution to this problem.

Here is the JSON Response:

```
{
    "messages": [
       {
           "id": "4323",
           "date": "07/01/17 23:22",
           "text": "This is a test message"
       },
       {
           "id": "4324",
           "date": "07/01/17 23:23",
           "text": "This is a test message 2"
       },
       {
           "id": "4326",
           "date": "07/01/17 23:25",
           "text": "This is a test message3"
       }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Could you include a sample JSON file you are parsing? Even better, a playground that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734982/parsing-nested-array-of-dictionaries-using-object-mapper/41735194#41735194 JSON Parsing is mentioned in thousands of questions

Comment: @kkoltzau you got the JSON file as well

Comment: @UmairAfzal this don't help me here :/

Comment: @PavlosNicolaou please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an update, the following code, which can run in a playground, demonstrates that the original code runs fine:

```
class Messages: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var date: String?
    var text: String?
}

var messagesSet = [Messages]()
let str = "{\"messages\": [{\"id\": \"4323\", \"date\": \"07/01/17 23:22\",\"text\": \"This is a test message\"}, {\"id\": \"4324\", \"date\": \"07/01/17 23:23\", \"text\": \"This is a test message 2\"}, {\"id\": \"4326\", \"date\": \"07/01/17 23:25\", \"text\": \"This is a test message3\"}]}"
let data = str.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
    if let messageList = jsonData["messages"] as? [Any] {
        for messageInfo in messageList {
            let message = Messages()
            if let info = messageInfo as? [String:Any] {
                if let id = info["id"] as? String {
                    message.id = id
                }
                if let date = info["date"] as? String {
                    message.date = date
                }
                if let text = info["text"] as? String {
                    message.text = text
                }
                messagesSet.append(message)
                messagesSet
            } else {
                NSLog("Failed to get message info dicgtionary")
            }
        }
        NSLog("Completed with data: \(messagesSet.count)")
    } else {
        NSLog("Failed to get messages")
    }
} catch let error {
    print("Decoding error \(error)")
}
```

The issue, as far I can tell (for those who are interested in what happened) is that the OP thought that their inability to print a `Messages` object was due to a code issue. Whereas it can simply be fixed by overriding the `description` property of the `Messages` object (since it is a sub-class of `NSObject`) as follows:

```
class Messages: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var date: String?
    var text: String?

    override var description: String {
        return "Message: ID - \(id), Content - \(text)"
    }
}
```

This is just for the reference of anybody else who might be interested.

Comment: the problem is that in the if statements I can print message.text and get the message.. but when I append the message into the messagesSet I cannot use the message after that.

The issue is adding data from an object in an array.

Comment: I understand that, but the code you've provided does not have any issues which could cause what you are seeing. Which is why having the full project code would help in figuring out what is going on ...

Comment: See the code that I just added to my answer. If you put that in a playground, it works. So you can just modify that to make any additional changes you need to make.

Comment: [here is the playground I added in github](https://github.com/p4vlos/getMessages)

Comment: Thanks for the playground :) That works fine (once I made a couple of changes to execute the fetch instead the playground terminating immediately) and it fetches 91 messages. So your code is fine. There are no issues :) If you want, I can post the updated playground code so that you can test for yourself ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138726/discussion-between-pavlos-nicolaou-and-fahim).

Comment: How can I use the text and id afterwards? because we are adding all in a string?

Comment: You'd simply refer to the relevant property of the object instance. For example, use `let msg = messagesSet[0]` to get one instance of `Messages` from the array and then use `msg.text` to get the `text` property and `msg.id` to get the `id` property.