# Json response gets only last row in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, nsjsonserialization

hi i am trying to get the son response from the server and the following is the response i get from server while using postman

```
{
  "stories": [
{
  "image_url": "http://storybox.dk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Hansa.jpg",
  "name": "New story",
  "story_key": "ahJlfnN0b3J5Ym94LWJhY2tlbmRyEgsSBVN0b3J5GICAgIC8oYIKDA"
},
{
  "image_url": "http://storybox.dk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Hansa.jpg",
  "name": "Story of Foo the fox.",
  "story_key": "ahJlfnN0b3J5Ym94LWJhY2tlbmRyEgsSBVN0b3J5GICAgID4woQKDA"
}]
}
```

but when i try to get the values inside the stories tag as array it gets only one value as
     self.StoryListArr = (reponsedict.value(forKey: "stories") as? NSArray)!

```
 (
   {
    "image_url" = "http://storage.googleapis.com/storybox-backend.appspot.com/5649391675244544/Screenshot_from_2017-03-16_113338.png";
    name = "Story of Foo";
    "story_key" = ahJlfnN0b3J5Ym94LWJhY2tlbmRyEgsSBVN0b3J5GICAgID4woQKDA;
   }
)
```

please advice how to deal this

when i try to print response dict it shows only one value in it

```
{
stories =     (
            {
        "image_url" = "http://storage.googleapis.com/storybox-backend.appspot.com/5649391675244544/Screenshot_from_2017-03-16_113338.png";
        name = "Story of Foo";
        "story_key" = ahJlfnN0b3J5Ym94LWJhY2tlbmRyEgsSBVN0b3J5GICAgID4woQKDA;
    }
);
}
```

Comment: try `reponsedict["stories"] as! [[String:Any]]`

Comment: Use swifty json. It's _much_ easier.

Comment: I would recommend using ObjectMapper. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734982/parsing-nested-array-of-dictionaries-using-object-mapper/41735194#41735194) is an example

Comment: hi i tried to print responsedict and it shows only one value inside the stories tag, i had added it in the question

Comment: I think problem is about your api. check it again about return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use NSArray in Swift. Simply cast the object to [Dictionary].

```
if let stories = responsedict["stories"] as? [Dictionary<String,String>] {
    print(stories) 
}
```

Comment: when i try to print the response dict it shows only one value in it

`print(reponsedict)

{
    stories =     (
                {
            "image_url" = "http://storage.googleapis.com/storybox-backend.appspot.com/5649391675244544/Screenshot_from_2017-03-16_113338.png";
            name = "Story of Foo";
            "story_key" = ahJlfnN0b3J5Ym94LWJhY2tlbmRyEgsSBVN0b3J5GICAgID4woQKDA;
        }
    );
}`

Comment: Try printing responsedict["stories"] to make sure that you have more than one value in the response in swift

Comment: Is the request in postman the exact same as the one in your code?

Comment: responsedict["stories"] prints

`(
        {
        "image_url" = "http://storage.googleapis.com/storybox-backend.appspot.com/5649391675244544/Screenshot_from_2017-03-16_113338.png";
        name = "Story of Foo";
        "story_key" = ahJlfnN0b3J5Ym94LWJhY2tlbmRyEgsSBVN0b3J5GICAgID4woQKDA;
    }
)`

contains only one value

Comment: Are you sure that the request is the exact same as the one you did in Postman?

Comment: sorry its my mistake with the url. thanks for your help

Comment: Sure, glad you found the cause

Comment: i am creating a story app with list of stories in home screen and details page on selecting the story i have array of stories on clicking the next story i want to load the contents of the next story with some animation like flipping the page suggest any ideas in swift 3

Comment: There are lot of ways to animate that. You can look at custom segue animations or just the `UIView.animate` function