# Swift 3 Parsing JSON nesting issue

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to parse some json data and I'm struggling to understand how to pull out and assign the nested values. I can manage the first level but when it comes any further I struggle.

I have an parseProductsData function which receives the data and works fine along with the first level of nesting.
How can i parse  nested Json array of [“Options”: "values”],[”variants”].

This is my Json.

```js
{
  products: [
    {
      id: 8931647873,
      title: "A bug Life1123",
      body_html: "
Ban neckline
Printed front
Full sleeves
Straight hem
Printed back
100% khaddar shirt without embroidery
 
",
      vendor: "Sapphire",
      product_type: "Configurable Products",
      created_at: "2017-03-01T23:54:41+05:00",
      handle: "a-bug-life",
      updated_at: "2017-03-17T16:30:46+05:00",
      published_at: "2017-01-07T12:33:00+05:00",
      template_suffix: "",
      published_scope: "global",
      tags: "Khaddar, L, M, Women, XL, Yellow",
      variants: [...],
      options: [
        {
          id: 10702667329,
          product_id: 8931647873,
          name: "Size",
          position: 1,
          values: [
            "XXS",
            "S",
            "M",
            "L",
            "XL",
            "XXL"
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 10702667393,
          product_id: 8931647873,
          name: "Color",
          position: 2,
          values: [
            "Yellow"
          ]
        }
      ],
      images: [
        {
          id: 20808811009,
          product_id: 8931647873,
          position: 1,
          created_at: "2017-03-01T23:54:41+05:00",
          updated_at: "2017-03-01T23:54:41+05:00",
          src: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1814/9759/products/a_bugs_life.jpg?v=1488394481",
          variant_ids: []
        },
        {
          id: 20808811073,
          product_id: 8931647873,
          position: 2,
          created_at: "2017-03-01T23:54:41+05:00",
          updated_at: "2017-03-01T23:54:41+05:00",
          src: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1814/9759/products/a_bugs_life..jpg?v=1488394481",
          variant_ids: []
        },
        {
          id: 20808811137,
          product_id: 8931647873,
          position: 3,
          created_at: "2017-03-01T23:54:41+05:00",
          updated_at: "2017-03-01T23:54:41+05:00",
          src: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1814/9759/products/a_bugs_life.__2.jpg?v=1488394481",
          variant_ids: []
        }
      ],
      image: {...}
    },
```

```
func parseProductsData() {
    Alamofire.request(BASE_URL+"/admin/products.json").responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result
        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            if let list = dict["products"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                for i in 0..<list.count {
                    print(list[i])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use swiftyjson

Comment: i’m using in an other function. Ganesh Kumar

Comment: But facing same problem :)

Comment: Instead of getting all the values manually, You can [ObjectMapper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwirnvv8yMbTAhWBWxoKHdI5C24QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FHearst-DD%2FObjectMapper&usg=AFQjCNFyUn25wAdc4YI3J79e10bh5EsWTQ&sig2=JeIkBfYEvZo15RBQyU8nBg). And [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734982/parsing-nested-array-of-dictionaries-using-object-mapper/41735194#41735194) you can find and example for nested data.

Comment: @GaneshKumar Can you explain? how is it parse by using swiftyJson?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you have to do is to understand the **hierarchy** and data type so that you can typecast into correct format.
Here your structure is mostly like **array of Dictionaries**, on your key "product" you will fetch an array of dict and store it into a variable say list. You can now iterate the list and fetch the dict. Then later from dict you can get the values on keys say "**id**", "**title**", "**vendor**" and **typecast** into **string**. And for keys like "**options**", "**images**", you again have to typecast it into **array of dictionaries** and the process goes on the same. Just understand the data type and typecast it in the given format.

```
func parseProductsData() {
        Alamofire.request(BASE_URL+"/admin/products.json").responseJSON { response in
            let result = response.result
            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                if let list = dict["products"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                    for dict in 0..<list {
                        //Now if you want to fetch the value on key "Options", you can see that your list of product holds an array Of Dictionary
                        //so all you have to do is

                        let arrOFOptions = dict["options"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]

                        //Same goes for variants

                        let arrOfVariants = dict["variants"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use Swift 3 Dictionary value type Any instead of AnyObject `as? [String: Any] ` or `as? [[String: Any]]` for array of dictionaries

Comment: Note that when using AnyObject your values (Double, Int, Float) are converted to NSNumber

Comment: @LeoDabus : Yes, i totally agree with you. I used that methodology just cz the question was asked in that format only. :)

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you explain how is it implement by using SwiftyJson?