# How to parse this json string in swift 3

Tags: json, swift3

I am new in swift 3 development. I could not parse the following json string getting from server. Can anybody help me to parse the data correctly.

```
"{\"code\": \"C001\", \"message\": {\"trxNo\": \"XXX\", \"id\": \"A88\", \"desc\": \"test\"}}"

Class T{
  code:String = ""
  message:Message = Message()
}   

Class Message {
  trxNo:String=""
  id:String=""
  desc:String=""
}
```

I want to parse the above string to Class T

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43773720/how-to-parse-this-json-string-in-swift-3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734982/parsing-nested-array-of-dictionaries-using-object-mapper/41735194#41735194

Comment: Show us your tried