# Swift - Parse array in nested JSON Object not working

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, dictionary

```
let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments])
        if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String:Any] {
            if let tJsonObj = xResponse["d"] as? [[String:Any]] {
               // not working here...
            }
        }
```

The tJsonObj variable does not get my json array content.
My json looks like this:

```
{"d": "[{\"title\":\"xxx\",\"timestamp\":\"2017-10-16 23:53:40\"},{\"title\":\"Mein Test iPhone 7\",\"timestamp\":\"2017-10-17 18:16:24\"}]"}
```

I hope someone can help - thanks!

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734982/parsing-nested-array-of-dictionaries-using-object-mapper/41735194#41735194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for key `d` is another JSON string. You need to use `JSONSerialization` twice

```
do {
  if let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any],
     let tJsonObj = responseJSON["d"] as? String {
        if let innerJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(tJsonObj.utf8)) as? [[String:Any]] { 
           for item in innerJSON {
              print(item)
           }
        }
  }
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner JSON for `d` looks escaped. Valid JSON should look something like:

```
{"d": "[{"title":"xxx","timestamp":"2017-10-16 23:53:40"},...
```

Where is your JSON coming from?

Comment: The JSON coming from my server. Objects are created with JavaScriptSerializer. Im sure the JSON ist valid.